# dplyr: error with rowwise mutate with NA

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I am getting strange errors with row-wise `mutate` in `dplyr`. Here is an example:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(5), b = rnorm(5))
df[2,'b'] <- NA
```

There is no trouble with `sum`, but summary functions are problematic:

```
mutate(rowwise(df), sum(a, b, na.rm = T)) # works

mutate(rowwise(df), mean(a, b, na.rm = T))
#! Error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
mutate(rowwise(df), median(a, b, na.rm = T))
#! Error: unused argument (-0.820468384118015)
```

Now, we can try to `NA` in the first column:

```
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(5), b = rnorm(5))
df[2,'a'] <- NA

mutate(rowwise(df), sum(a, b, na.rm = T)) # works

mutate(rowwise(df), mean(a, b, na.rm = T))
#! no error, but returns `NaN`
mutate(rowwise(df), median(a, b, na.rm = T))
#! Error: unused argument (-0.820468384118015)
```

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong here. I think the expected behavior should be the same as:

```
as.data.frame(apply(df, 1, mean, na.rm = T)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Mean = mean(c(a,b), na.rm=TRUE))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is that you are calling  `mean` and `median` incorrectly.

While `sum` can take any number of arguments and will just add them all, `mean` and `median` take in only ONE `x` argument to take the mean/median of.

Just like if `a` and `b` were vectors and you wanted the mean of the combined vector you'd use `mean(c(a, b))` rather than `mean(a,b)`, you do the same here:

```
mutate(rowwise(df), mean=mean(c(a, b), na.rm = T), med=median(c(a, b), na.rm=T))
```

(side note: you are only calculating the mean and median of 2 values at a time here, so the mean equals the median anyway...)